# Set MS Office as predefined

Tags: office, playonlinux

I installed MS Office using Play on Linux, but when I click on my file (.docx or other) for "*open with: Microsoft Word*", there isn't in the possible choices!

Is there a way to open directly the file without open first Microsoft Word (and select: *open file -> myfile.docx*)?

Comment: You can add it to the choices in the _Open with…/Other application_ menu.

Comment: @lemonslice I've already tried, even with _/Other application / Se all_ there isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Playonlinux
- Select 'Configure'
- Select your virtual drive (e.g. Office2007)
- Under 'General' tab click 'Make a new shortcut for this virtual drive'
- Select the icon you want (e.g. WINWORD.EXE) and press next
- Give it a name (let's say MSWord)
- Close Playonlinux.
- Look in $HOME for `MSWord.desktop`
- Copy that to `~/.local/share/applications`
- Select a `.docx` file (or what you need), right-click, 'Properties', 'Open with', Other application, 'Show all applications', look for **MSWord**. ('Set as default' should be enabled.)

If the desktop file has no proper icon, look for it in `~/.PlayOnLinux/icones/full_size`. Copy it to `~/.local/share/icons` and rename it so as to add the png extension (e.g. `winword.png`) then edit the `Icon` line of the desktop file (e.g. `Icon=winword`). Other lines that are worth editing are maybe:

```
Name=Microsoft Office Word;
```

and

```
Categories=Office;WordProcessor;
```

Comment: you are my hero!

Answer (score 2):

You should look for the `.desktop` file of the Microsoft Word (in `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs`) and append `%F` to the line that starts with `Exec=`.